# tab_spanner returning column does not exist

Tags: r, gt

I am trying to create a table using the `gt` package. Now when I try to add a `spanner` to the table, the code returns an error.

```
gt_tbl =
  gt(data = merged.dfs) %>%
  tab_header(
    title = "Two sample K-S Test Statistics for 2004") %>%
  tab_spanner(
    label = "Pair 1 (VIC SC and PCA SC)",
    columns = c(D.Max.04.p1, p.value.04.p1)
  ) %>%
  tab_spanner(
    label = "Pair 2 (VIC SCB1 and PCA SCB1)",
    columns = c(D.Max.04.p2, p.value.04.p2)
  )
```

Error

```
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `0.19` doesn't exist.
```

Please note that when I run the the following code, the table gets created, and it can be seen the columns do actually exist. How can this error be fixed?

```
gt_tbl =
      gt(data = merged.dfs) %>%
      tab_header(
        title = "Two sample K-S Test Statistics for 2004")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `columns` argument is being evaluated, and so the code is looking for columns which have names equal to the values of `merged.dfs$D.Max.04.p1` and `merged.dfs$p.value.04.p1`, hence the first column it is looking for is `merged.dfs$0.19`. There are two ways you can modify the columns argument:

Use quoted strings:

```
columns = c("D.Max.04.p1", "p.value.04.p1")
```

use the `vars` function (as shown in the example for `?tab_spanner`)

```
 columns = vars(D.Max.04.p1, p.value.04.p1)
```

Of course the same change will need also to be applied to the second `tab_spanner` call too.

Comment: On a side note, can you also please tell me that which function has the `caption` argument to add captions to the table like Table 1?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. It'll also be a more useful contribution to the site if you ask this as a new question, rather than it being hidden away in the comments.